# SQLITE add a column counting values in other columns

Tags: sqlite

I have a sql table containing some values as in the example.

```
 id value
 1  value1
 2  value2
 3  value3
 4  value1
 5  value2
 6  value1
```

I need to add a column that have to increment a counter each time a "value1" is present.

```
 id value  session
 1  value1    1
 2  value2    1
 3  value3    1
 4  value1    2
 5  value2    2
 6  value1    3
```

Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: Is it related only to 'value1', or you want to count other values as well?

Comment: When a "value1" is present in the table I have to increase a counter, so all values in the "session" column will have the same counter value until a next "value1"  is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql subquery with agregation

- Your table

```
    CREATE TABLE test (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, value nvarchar (10));
```

- Populate with data

```
    INSERT INTO test(value) values ('value1'),('value2'),
       ('value3'),('value1'),('value2'),('value3'),
       ('value1'),('value1'),('value2');
```

- Enjoy

```
    SELECT a.id,a.value, (SELECT COUNT(b.id) 
        FROM   test b
        WHERE  a.id>=b.id and b.value = 'value1') session
    FROM   test a
    ORDER  BY a.id;
```